# What is the C# equivalent to Java ChromeOptions.setExperimentalOptions()?

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have automated android chrome browser with the below code:

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
ChromeOptions options=new ChromeOptions();  

options.setExperimentalOptions("androidPackage", "com.android.chrome");
capabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);

WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://Users//Documents//Appium//ChromeDriver//chromedriver.exe");
String url="http://yahoo.com";
driver.get(url);
```

I am trying to automate android chrome browser using C# (Visual Studio) but can't find the equivalent code. I am using this but not working:

```
Capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
ChromeOptions options1=new ChromeOptions();
options1.AddAdditionalCapability("androidPackage", "com.android.chrome",);
Driver = new ChromeDriver(Chrome_Driver, options1);
```

Comment: I have raised the question here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/chromedriver-users/XTeGu710C2Q

Comment: Did you find an answer to this? The below answer posted by Pavel I find lacking because it uses RemoteWebDriver instead of ChromeDriver. Also, I do not want to instance the driver with a uri - I want to do that somewhere else in my code.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
chromeOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("androidPackage", "com.android.chrome");

driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://seleniumhubaddress:4444/wd/hub"), chromeOptions.ToCapabilities());
```

Comment: AddAdditionalCapability no longer supported by Selenium Chrome think it was depreciated in version 4

Comment: Use ```chromeOptions.AddAdditionalOption("androidPackage", "com.android.chrome");``` instead.

https://ultimateqa.com/selenium-4/